# How to use a linux machine as router for some connections?

Tags: linux, networking

I have the following problem:

1. A computer with win 10 that has access to some servers (lets call A)
2. A workstation computer with linux in other network (lets call B)
3. The server has access to both networks. (lets call C)

I desire to access from A to B through C. How to set routes in these computers ?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for server fault, but there are other details you'll need to provide such as:
Are there any other computers on A or B's Network, and do you want them to have access too?
What kind of access do you need? Full access? or just one port?
Do you want B or B's Network to have access back to A?
Are they on different subnets?
Are you using VLANS?
For example, just setting a route from A's network to B's network might not give you what you want, especially if you only want A to have access and not A's entire network.

Comment: That's very easy. But what about security? Are there any requirements?

Comment: Basically I want to access to ports 22 and 9001 published in computer C  from computer A using as a router the C machine,. that has access to both networks.
. 
I want to set the routes manually, where can I have examples. 

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer for such a question earlier, where I had a single workstation with two network cards acting as a bridge. In this case, if you need to access a specific port on the other machine (say port 80 for http or 5900 for VNC), then you simply need to forward a port from C to B. If you need direct access, however, you will need to do more complex routing and setup C as a router itself.

As far as port forwarding is concerned the final solution I used was jTCPfwd, since it is extremely light, works well and is compatible across systems.

http://jtcpfwd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The "complex routing" is actually easier than setting up port forwarding manually.

Comment: @DanielB, PLEASE LET ME KNOW, I'm dying to know. I've been looking for a solution to this since AGES!

Comment: @DanielB I just teste jtcpfwd and is the glory ! Genius !